# Looping through $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, loops

I have a MySQL database with the table "chapters". The table "chapters" has three columns: (1) id, (2) name, (3) password.

I am using PHP to dynamically output the data from "chapters" into text boxes. The result looks something like this:

```
<form name="current_chapters" method="post" action="UpdateChapters.php">    
<input type = 'text' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'>
<input type = 'text' name='name' value='{$row['name']}'>
<input type = 'password' name='password' value='New Password'>
<input type = 'submit'>
</form>
```

Note that this page is used to reset (not display) passwords, hence the "New Password" default value.

I am looking for the best way to loop through all of that $_POST data and then update the original "chapters" table that this data originally came from.

I tried playing around with looping through $_POST via foreach and changing the input names to "id[]", "name[]", and "password[]", but it doesn't seem to be the most elegant approach, especially with the id part...you end up with things like id[0] = 133, which just seems messy.

Any recommendations on how to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to loop through the $_POST? It's an associative array, and obviously you already know the keys?

Comment: I thought I had to loop through $_POST because the number of entries being displayed is dynamic...it depends on how many are in the database. Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: I just don't see the point in iterating over the $_POST array, using `$_POST['id']` is just as helpful as the answer given witch `case 'id'`, in both cases you need to statically set the key name.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass in structured data using `$_POST`. Which eases handling multiple fields of the same type:

```
<input name="book[12][name]" value="name of book 12">
<input name="book[12][password]" value="password for book12">
<input name="book[99][name]" value="name of book 99">
<input name="book[99][password]" value="password for book99">
```

Which will create data structure in `$_POST` like the following:

```
[book] => Array
    (
        [12] => Array
            (
                [name] => name of book 12
                [password] => password for book 12
            )

        [99] => Array
            (
                [name] => name of book 99
                [password] => password for book 99
            )

    )
```

Which you can then iterate as follows:

```
foreach ($_POST['book'] as $book_id => $book) {
  // Watch out for SQL injection
  $sql = "UPDATE book SET name = '{$book['name']}', password = '{$book['password']}' WHERE id = $book_id";
}
```

Comment: Also, wouldn't I need to do another foreach loop through $book, as that itself is an array (consisting of name and password)?